# Combinatorics: Head or Cross of a coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A coin (Heads or Cross) is flipped 25 times. Consider $X = \text{number of
> times that comes out cross}$. How many are the chances that at the end of the $25$ rolls $X$ is less than or
> equal to $1$?

I think ${25 \choose 2} = 300 $ but too much... The $2$ comes from $1\le x$ so $x =1 \lor x=0$.

How can I solve that?

Comment: @AdamRubinson No that's actually what the text asks

Comment: It's probably supposed to be "heads and cross."

Comment: @saulspatz fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are

- $\binom{25}{0} = 1$ ways to toss the coin 25 times, obtaining zero "cross"s,
- $\binom{25}{1} = 25$ ways to toss the coin 25 times, obtaining one "cross", and
- $2^{25} = 33\,554\,432$ possible sequences of 25 coin tosses.

So the probability of getting $0$ or $1$ "cross"s is
$$  \frac{\binom{25}{0} + \binom{25}{1}}{2^{25}} = \frac{1 + 25}{33\,554\,432} = \frac{13}{16\,777\,216}  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...

Take cases on if $x=0,1$.

If $x=0$, then every flip must be head, so
$$\frac{1}{2^{25}}$$
chance.
If $x=1$ then there must be one cross and all others heads. This happens with chance
$$\frac{25}{2^{25}}.$$
Thus the answer is
$$\frac{26}{2^{25}}.$$